# Android BaseAdapters & Multiple Listviews

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, adapter

I am currently creating a basic news aggregator app for Android, I have so far managed to create multiple HorizontalListViews derived from this: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

I am parsing all data from live JSON objects and arrays.

The process goes something like this:

1) Start app 
2) Grab a JSON file which lists all feeds to display 
3) Parse feed titles and article links, add each to an array 
4) Get number of feeds from array and create individual HorizontalListView for each. i.e. "Irish Times".
5) Apply BaseAdapter "mAdapter" to each HorizontalListView during creation.

My baseadapter is responsible for populating my HorizontalListViews by getting each title and thumbnail.

My problem is however that all my feeds seem to contain the same articles and thumbnails. Now I am only new to Android so I'm not 100% sure whats going wrong here. See screenshot below.

Do I need to create a new BaseAdaptor for each HorizontalListview or can I use the same one to populate all my listviews with unique data.

Here's some code to help explain what I mean:

**1) OnCreate method to get JSON data, parse it, get number of feeds and create each HorizontalListView**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);

    //--------------------JSON PARSE DATA------------------
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(sourcesUrl);

    //Parse feed titles and article list
    getFeeds(json); 

    //Create Listviews
    for(int i = 0; i < feedTitle.size()-1; i++){
        //getArticleImage(i);
        addHorzListView(i);
        articleArrayCount++;//Used to mark feed count for adaptor to know which array position to look at and retrieve data from.
     //Each array position i.e. [1] represents a HorizontalListview and its related articles 
    }   

}
```

**2) addHorzListView method, used to create HorizontalListView and apply adaptor**

```
//Method used to dynamically add HorizontalListViews
public void addHorzListView(int count){
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);  
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview, mainLayout,false);

    //Set lists header name
    TextView header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header);
    header.setText(feedTitle.get(count));

    //Create individual listview
    HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listviewReuse);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //add listview to array list
    listviewList.add(listview); 


    mainLayout.addView(view, count);    
}
```

**3) Baseadaptor itself:**

```
private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    private OnClickListener mOnButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HorizontalListViewDemo.this);
            builder.setMessage("hello from " + v);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Cool", null);
            builder.show();

        }
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return noOfArticles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

//Each listview is populated with data here
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(getArticleTitle(position));
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01)) .execute(getArticleImage(position));
        Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);


        return retval;
    }

};
```

The adapter mAdapter is currently displaying the articles from the last HorizontalListView that calls it.

Currently I am using the same BaseAdaptor for each ListView as I figured it populated the listview as soon as its called but i looks as though a BaseAdaptor can only be called once, I really dont know.

I want to dynamically populate feeds though without having to create a new Adaptor manually for each HorizontalListView.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to instantiate a new adapter for every listview? So you're using the same adapter but different instances. Using the same instance is not possible afaik.

Comment: Yeah it works when I create new adapters with new names like mAdapter2 but not new instances of mAdapter you see I am dynamically grabbing feeds so it wouldn't really be a proper news aggregator if I only defined say 4 adapters manually but the feed list had 6 feeds. Is there any way I can dynamically create new adapters do you know?

Comment: I would try it this way: Make your own adapter class extending BaseAdapter and then instead of setAdapter(mAdapter) use setAdapter(new ownBaseAdapter()). If you need to access the adapter somewhere else in the code, you can call it with listview.getAdapter()...

Comment: hmm I converted my adapter into a class extending BaseAdapter and implemented as you suggested but I just got the same results. I'm wondering can you make an Array of Adapters maybe and call them individually?

Answer (score 0):

So...you got the same info in 4 listview, right? In that case you only need oneAdapter populating 4 listview.
An adapter just provide the views which are visible in that moment to the listview (if it is implemented in the right way) so you can reuse the adapter if the info contained is the same.